# Why a webpage is showing "Deceptive site ahead" error in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

Whenever I open the portfolio page in Chrome of my website chrome throws the deceptive site ahead error.

Why am I getting this? It's not a phishing webpage.

IEEE-PESCE gallery page:

`http://ieeepesce.com/portfolio.html`

Comment: Virustotal scans seem ok: [1](http://www.virustotal.com/#/url/979cc30bab502679a3ad536d5928131ef534b132e8953af97455e6957b83cfbc/detection) [2](http://www.virustotal.com/#/url/e8ebf24e7176ba4e3fde92b5e4eb1b19ba74413400044e2504f09f939329b808/detection)

Answer (score 1):

Chrome shows this error when it perceives the site to use phishing or social engineering techniques to get data from the user without the users full knowledge or consent. This can sometimes be a mistake and there are steps you can take to claim your site as legitimate.

As a side note, so far I’ve been able to access your site myself in three browsers so the problem may already be resolved. You may want to try it once more in an incognito window to see if browser cache is responsible for showing you this error. See here in how to open an incognito window: https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95464?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en

If not, Google has a help guide for site owners to resolve these issues. Ultimately what you might want to do is create a Google Search Console account and request a review of your site by Google so they can remove the warning. The guide explaining the process is here:

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6350487?hl=en